# Assuming a Linux box has a huge disk cache, is it significantly beneficial to performance for applications to buffer writes?

Tags: linux, performance, caching, disk

```
$ free -wh
              total        used        free      shared     buffers       cache   available
Mem:           125G         30G         59G        1.3G        837M         35G         92G
Swap:          7.6G        700K        7.6G
```

I understand that applications can buffer disk writes for various reasons not necessarily for performance, but assuming one is going to write complete "records" 100 times per second, of perhaps 1k in size, in one call to the os level write function (this one)

```
#include <unistd.h>
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

Should these be accumulated into near 4k blocks before writing or is there little benefit in doing that?

I'm talking about **significant benefits,** worth the extra effort, risk and potential data loss of buffering multiple records internally.

Does the Linux disk cache "abstract away" the need for apps to do their own buffering?

I know there are always exceptions to blanket rules and your answers can bring that up but I'm talking mainly about applications that need to write sequential log type files perhaps 100 per second.

Comment: For C streams you can try with setvbuf to check performance each way.

Comment: AFAIK, the OS has its own cache as well as the libc. The OS buffers help a lot to speed up writes and cached reads on HDDs or slow SSD, but not always on fast Nvme M2 SSDs. The libc cache help to reduce the system calls that would be pretty expensive, especially for 1k chunks.